# I/O Error Permission Denied, qBitorrent, secondary NTFS drive

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive, qbittorrent

Ubuntu 18.04
qBitorrent 4.0.3 (64-bit)

I have been working on this for some time now and it's doing my head in.

I have tried remounting the drive with read/write permissions (unsure if this was successful though, permissions info just shows root as owner and I "can't change permissions because I am not owner"). I can create and delete files on the drive though, so I assume I have rw access. I tried to follow steps to chown on the drive, but it doesn't let me, and I suspect this is a rabbit hole. The original error said "read-only access" which is why I tried these steps, but now the error has changed to "permission denied" and I am lost.

qBittorent has been working fine for months, I have had this issue show itself before but usually a reboot or fiddle around with mount settings and the problem goes away. I also tried running an ntfsfix command to remove any windows hibernation headers, but nothing.

Not sure what to try next. Removing and re-telling QB where to point to does nothing.

Comment: Your drive may be failing and your last hope is Windows tools. Ntfsfix command merely tells Windows that the partition needs checking. You can't error correct NTFS partitions from Linux.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thank's. I will try a scan and repair through Windows then (I have dual boot)

Comment: Drive is fine, no problems, error still occurring.

Comment: All my searches so far for this problem refer to NTFS, but I have a very similar problem with a NAS ext4 folder mounted through NFS. Files are downloaded OK and the folder can be read from/written to, but it seems like this IO error appears when seeding. I haven’t downloaded the torrent all at once and it always seems to be the most recently downloaded file that has the problem.

Mainly annoying when combined with Gnome’s unconfigurable notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Given your description matches mine to the last detail, likely the problem is also the same:

There seems to be a race condition with multiple asynchronous I/O threads, when one thread creates a file and another one attempts to write to it before the file exists. Although qBittorrent likely has a mutex to prevent this, the NTFS drivers might be returning before the underlying filesystem changes are actually applied.

**Possible solution**: Set those [AIO threads](https://www.libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#aio_threads) from 10 (default) to 1 under *Tools* > *Preferences* > *Advanced*, then scrolled down to *libtorrent Section* > *Asynchronous I/O threads*.

It's not great, and might reduce performance when downloading multiple torrents, but until this bug gets fixed it will provide a better experience.